# Parse JSON file and output string after a string of alphabets and characters

Tags: python, json, regex, shell, awk

The file looks like:

`{"project":"platform/xxxxx/xxxxxx/build/repo","branch":"xxxxx_xx.xxxxx.xxx.1.0-dev","id":"T19797TIE76757IT78689899G","number":"1917095","subject":"xxxxx-2.0: blah blah blah","owner":{"name":"David","email":"david@xxxx.com","username":"david"},"url":"https://link_to_repo.com/1917095","createdOn":1493282302,"lastUpdated":1493813064,"sortKey":"000899786887","open":false,"status":"MERGED"`

I require the number "1917095" after the string "number":" or also after string "https://link_to_repo.com/ ,so the output should only give these numbers even if position of the field changes.

I tried to achieve it by:

```
awk -F'[,:"]' '{ print $23 }' file_name
```

which gives me the result but I need to find a better solution.

So I need help in achieving this with help of python(I am new to it) or else any tool in bash?

Comment: Is the data actually all on one line? The question formatting makes it appear to have a newline after `"David`. Why is a "better" solution needed?

Comment: is it json file?

Comment: @lit- No the data is like- {"project":"platform/xxxxx/xxxxxx/build/repo","branch":"xxxxx_xx.xxxxx.xxx.1.0-dev","id":"T19797TIE76757IT78689899G","number":"1917095","subject":"xxxxx-2.0: blah blah blah","owner":{"name":"David ","email":"david@xxxx.com","username":"david"},"url":"https://link_to_repo.com/1917095","createdOn":1493282302,"lastUpdated":1493813064,"sortKey":"000899786887","open":false,"status":"MERGED" {"type":"stats","rowCount":1,"runTimeMilliseconds":3} , newline starts after "MERGED" and then {"type":"stats","rowCount":1,"runTimeMilliseconds":3} follows.

Comment: @lit I need a better solution because with my command awk is separating the fields with delimiter and then displaying fields, but I need to automate this job, so if the fields placement changes, then the desired output might not be in field $23, so its better if i can extract the number from "https://link_to_repo.com/1917095" with a command which searches for and gives the output whatever comes after "https://link_to_repo.com/ . That's my point.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes it is but I have only shown a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex can be used to select only the number.

```
$ awk '{ if (match($0,/number":"([0-9]*)"/,m)) print m[1] }' af.txt
1917095
```

If getting it from the URL is desired.

```
$ awk '{ if (match($0,/link_to_repo.com\/([0-9]*)"/,m)) print m[1] }' af.txt
1917095

$ awk '{ if (match($0,/link_to_repo.com\/([[:digit:]]*)"/,m)) print m[1] }' af.txt
1917095
```

I tried very hard to make and example using `\d` to find digits. That is a Perl extension and not available in awk regex.

If these do not work, what is your version of awk? `awk --version`

Comment: It throws following error- "awk: line 1: syntax error at or near , "

Comment: I have edited the answer to show that these work on my system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I realized I am using mawk and you must be using gawk. So I installed gawk and then all of the above worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this:

For only a json in the file:

Create a file like "string.py" for example and put the following code in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               

import sys, json                                                                

with open(sys.argv[1]) as data_file:                                            
    data = json.load(data_file)                                                 
print(data[sys.argv[2]])
```

And then call it like:

```
python [file_name] [json_file] [json_attribute]
```

Example:

```
python string.py test.json number
```

With string search:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               

import sys                                                                      

with open(sys.argv[1]) as data_file:                                            
    data = data_file.readlines()                                                

a = '"number":"'                                                                
b = '","subject"'                                                               
d = ''.join(data)                                                               
result = d.split(a)[-1].split(b)[0]                                             
print(result)
```

And then call it like:

```
python [json_file]
```

Example:

```
python string.py
```

Comment: Thanks but it didnt help as I got the following error- File "string.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = json.load(data_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 9 column 1 (char 486 - 2168)

Comment: It did work but didn't fetch all the numbers, from my file it was also showing one number from one line, rest all ignored.

Comment: However I tried and achieved desired result with this but I am not sure how good is my approach as I am new to python-                          
import json

with open('file_name.json') as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        data = json.loads(line)
        if "number" in data:
            print data["number"]

Comment: It is good and better if the file you load is only json!
I did my answer with strings because I taught your file contains more then just json. Pls state in your question the answer you used.

Answer (score 0):

i have a little change your data , since you miss } in the end , and this code tested under python 3.6

```
data = {"project":"platform/xxxxx/xxxxxx/build/repo","branch":"xxxxx_xx.xxxxx.xxx.1.0-dev","id":"T19797TIE76757IT78689899G",
    "number":"1917095","subject":"xxxxx-2.0: blah blah blah","owner":{"name":"David","email":"david@xxxx.com","username":"david"},
    "url":"https://link_to_repo.com/1917095","createdOn":"1493282302","lastUpdated":"1493813064","sortKey":"000899786887","open":"false","status":"MERGED"}

 jsonobject = json.dumps(data)
 #print (jsonobject)
 jsonobjectToString = json.loads(jsonobject)
 #print (jsonobjectToString)

  print (jsonobjectToString["number"])


  =====
  1917095
```